# How to replace values between two rasters (matrix)?

Tags: r, raster

I have two rasters `r` and `r2`that I would like to replace some valus in `r` from `r1`

```
 library (raster)
 r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
 r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))

 r1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
 r1 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r))
```

If the value for any pixel in `r`  equals `40` put the corresponding (replace it with) values from `r1` .
so finally I will get `r` with values of `40` replaced with corresponding values from `r1`

well the two rasters here are identical but my data are not
Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you want to replace values in `r@data@values`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach. First, find the values in `r` that are equal to `255`. Second, replace these values with corresponding values from `r1`.

```
idx <- values(r) == 255
values(r)[idx] <- values(r1)[idx]
```

Comment: @hyat I suppose there's no way that is considerably faster.

Answer (score 2):

There are two common ways to make replacements in rasters. Here I profile two:

```
> library(raster)
> rm(list=ls())
> r = raster('G:\\Faculty\\Mann\\Projects\\India_Index_Insurance\\Data\\India\\MOD13Q1_2002193_h24v05.250m_16_days_EVI.tif')
> r1 = raster('G:\\Faculty\\Mann\\Projects\\India_Index_Insurance\\Data\\India\\MOD13Q1_2002193_h24v05.250m_16_days_EVI.tif')
> 
> ptm <- proc.time()
> idx <- values(r) <=0
> values(r)[idx] <- values(r1)[idx]
> proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
   2.76    0.73    7.19 
> 
> r = raster('G:\\Faculty\\Mann\\Projects\\India_Index_Insurance\\Data\\India\\MOD13Q1_2002193_h24v05.250m_16_days_EVI.tif')
> r1 = raster('G:\\Faculty\\Mann\\Projects\\India_Index_Insurance\\Data\\India\\MOD13Q1_2002193_h24v05.250m_16_days_EVI.tif')
> 
> ptm <- proc.time()
> index = r<=0
> r[index]=r1[index]
> proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
   5.44    0.89    9.20
```

If you are running this operation on a rasterstack or a large number of smaller rasters I would recommend learning foreach %dopar% to parallelize your code. Vignette here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf

If you are running it on one or two very large rasters (running into memory limits) you should read the vignette on handling large rasters: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/functions.pdf

For a detailed discussion of R data types (and explanations of why some things are so slow) see Hadley Wickam's site http://adv-r.had.co.nz/ in particular: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html#implementation-performance